# Intercept value passed to item editor?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, flash-builder, flex-spark

I'm trying to intercept the value that is taken from a DataGrid's GridColumn's itemRenderer and applied to the itemEditor, and vice-versa. I need to be able to format this value. However, my project is complex, so I may be focusing on the wrong idea in what I'm trying to accomplish. Please have a look and let me know if there's something else I could try.

I have a Spark DataGrid component (with ID **dg**) that I am dynamically populating from XML. I create an ArrayCollection from some nodes, and a regular Array from sub-nodes that is added as a property of the ArrayCollection. That ArrayCollection is then used as the dataProvider for the DataGrid.

Here is an example segment of a typical XML node and it's sub-nodes:

```
<item name="physOrderTable" text="" type="notes">
    <cols>
        <col id="0" text="Day/Time" />
        <col id="1" text="Order Type" />
        <col id="2" text="Physician's Orders" />
        <col id="3" text="Physician's Signature" />
    </cols>
    <rows>
        <row id="r0" name="" text="">
            <col id="0"><![CDATA[Tues 15:24]]></col>
            <col id="1"><![CDATA[General]]></col>
            <col id="2"><![CDATA[BMP, CBC, Cardiac Enzymes, ABG, EKG STAT, NS@ 125 mL/hr, Blood Sugar AC & HS, 02 via NC to keep oxygen saturation above 97%]]></col>
            <col id="3"><![CDATA[J. Nelms]]></col>
        </row>
    </rows>
</item>
```

Here is the code that reads through the XML and utilizes it:

```
protected function sparkDG_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    trace("grid created");
    var colsList:XMLList = xml.cols.col;
    var rowsList:XMLList = xml.rows.row;
    colAL = new ArrayList();

    for(var i:Number = 0; i < colsList.length(); i++)
    {
        var gc:GridColumn = new GridColumn();
        gc.maxWidth = 500;
        gc.resizable = false;
        gc.headerText = String(colsList[i].@text);
        gc.dataField = "col";
        gc.labelFunction = labelFunc;
        colAL.addItem(gc);
    }

    for each(var row:XML in XML(value).rows.children())
    {
        var rowArr:Array = new Array();

        for each(var col:XML in row.children())
        {
            if(col == "")
            {
                rowArr[Number(col.@id)] = "_";
            }else{
                rowArr[Number(col.@id)] = col;
            }
        }

        colAC.addItem({
            rowID: row.@id,
            rowName: row.@name,
            rowText: row.@text,
            col: rowArr
        });
    }

    dg.columns = colAL;
    dg.dataProvider = colAC;
}//
```

So I build the header for the DataGrid first, telling it to use the "col" dataField, which corresponds to the **.col** property of the **colAC** ArrayCollection. That **.col** property is the array of values for each cell of that row.

Now this part of code is important, as it displays the relevant index of the **.col** array by using the **.columnIndex**:

```
private function labelFunc(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String
{
    var displayText:String;
    var valArr:Array = new Array();

    if(column.dataField == "col")
    {
        valArr = item[column.dataField];
        displayText = String(valArr[column.columnIndex]);
    }

    return displayText;
}//
```

This is the only method I've been able to use to achieve the desired result. This all works fine, if all I want to do is merely display information. But I need to be able to edit the values in each cell, and apply this back to the dataProvider, as I need to rebuild XML with the updated values later.

I have tried everything I can possibly think of to be able to do this. I built my own itemRenderer, then my own itemEditor, then scrapped them because it felt like I was re-inventing the wheel. But was I? I tried reading through the code for the DataGrid, GridColumn, and related classes, but I couldn't find any reference to the itemEditor beyond it being an IFactory. I have no idea where or how it tells that IFactory to be a text input or whatever it is.

Here is my issue:

When I turn on the DataGrid's editing, and double-click a cell, it takes the entire array of the **col** dataField for that column's cell, converts that array to a string, and displays the entire string in the edit text box. If I cancel the editing, or save the editing, it sets the *string* to the **.col** property. Then the *labelFunction* tries reading that string as an array, and it crashes. I was able to get the *typeof* the **col** dataField and converting it to an array if it's a string, but I shouldn't have to.

I need to have it display *just* the value of the cell for that particular row and column when the instance of the itemEditor is created. When that value is changed, I need it to apply back to that column's index in the **.col** array of the dataProvider. So, similarly to how it displays information in the *labelFunction*, I need to edit the information and send it back.

I've seen lots of custom itemEditors and itemRenderers for GridColumns, but these are hard-coded in the MXML. My grid is almost entirely dynamically created, so that's unfortunately not an option for me, as I won't even know how many columns or rows there will be when the DataGrid is created. I tried using *rendererIsEditor*, but that only seems to be on the MXML instantiation of the GridColumn, as there's only *rendererIsEditable* in the ActionScript, and it doesn't seem to work (or I don't know how to use it as intended).

If anyone knows of a way to accomplish this, even just something else I should look at, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the gridItemEditorSession... Events:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#event:gridItemEditorSessionStart